# Detect iframe request in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, format, request

I have a iFrame tool, which should get rendered in a other format than my page. So I want to detect requests from iFrame like I can detect them from a iPhone. Is this possible?

Is there a special hint in the request header, that I could use, or could I manually enter one?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: Are you referring to an `<iframe>` tag, or to a some weird not-yet-released Apple device?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you get a request from an iPhone there will be send a "User Agent"-String like `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3` in the `request.user_agent` variable. Searching this string for `iPhone` can tell you that an iPhone is visiting your page.

An iframe is an [HTML tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) to include other pages within your page (eg. the Facebook like button uses this). This does not have to to anything with a specific browser, all modern browsers support this. You cannot tell on server side whether your page was called within an iframe or not. You can use some JavaScript in the client to find out if your current page is within an iframe and then send a notice to the server.

Best practice would be to add another paramter to your request like `?iframe=1` and use this param within your controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, thats what I would have done, and will do now, as there is no other solution... Thanks!

Comment: @arnep I was having an issue with your solution, the relevant question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694977/rails-3-dry-conditional-layout-for-iframes if you wanted to address it

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is to add a subdomain for your embeds. Then you can fire requests to the subdomain and evaluate `request.host`. This also allows for a separation of logic in controllers/views when using multiple subdomains.

**Example:**

iFrame

- `<iframe src="embed-subdomain.domain.com" />` instead of `<iframe src="domain.com" />`

Controller

- `iframe = request.host.include?("embed-subdomain.domain")`

*Disclaimer: This can get tricky if you utilize sessions and CNAMEs*